# "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" using PhoneGap IAP Plugin

Tags: iphone, cordova, in-app-purchase

We have implemented in-app purchases in one of our product's using Matt Kane's excellent plugin.  We are successfully processing purchases, but in doing remote debugging notice a large number of occurrences of the error "Cannot connect to iTunes Store", with error code 2.  According to the Apple reference below, this error is SKErrorPaymentCancelled, which seemingly indicates that the user has hit "Cancel."

I just wanted to be sure that these were real occurrences of a user actually hitting the "Cancel" button, not a technical failure in our code.  Any other PhoneGap iOS developers out there using the IAP plugin able to shed some light?

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/InAppPurchaseManager

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/StoreKitTypes/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16421002/2465934  you can refer this question for solution.