# Payment Transaction State Failed

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to make In-app purchase in my application using phonegap plugin which is https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/InAppPurchaseManager

but in sandbox testing i'm getting following error 
**plugins.inAppPurchaseManager.updatedTransactionCallback.apply(plugins.inAppPurchaseManager, ["PaymentTransactionStateFailed",0,"Cannot connect to iTunes Store","","",""])**

and then the application gets struck...can anyone help me out with this??

Answer (score 2):

Take a look inside of InAppPurchaseManager.js, and you'll see the first call of InAppPurchaseManager.prototype.updatedTransactionCallback is:

alert(state);

Replace that with PhoneGap's preferred:

navigator.notification.alert(state);

And it should clear up fine.